# undefined local variable or method when rendering in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a comment like system where the user can add a 'outcome' to a 'decision'.

Now i've rendered the form and the outcomes in the show.html.erb of 'decisions' but the outcomes give the following error: undefined local variable or method `outcomes' for #<#:0x007fc6046099e8>

My code:

controllers/outcomes_controller.rb

```
class OutcomesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @decision = Decision.find(params[:decision_id])
        @outcome = @decision.outcomes.create(params[:outcome].permit(:actual, :strength, :weakness))
          redirect_to decision_path(@decision)
    end
end
```

models/outcome.rb

```
class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
end
```

models/decision.rb

```
class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outcomes
end
```

decisions/show.html.erb

```
    <h1>Decision showpage</h1>

<h2><%= @decision.title %></h2>
<p><%= @decision.created_at %></p>
<p><%= @decision.forecast %></p>
<p><%= @decision.review_date %></p>

<%= render @decision.outcomes %>


<%= link_to "Delete Decision", decision_path(@decision), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

<%= render "outcomes/form" %>
<%= render "outcomes/outcome" %>
```

outcomes/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@decision, @decision.outcomes.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :actual %>:
  <%= f.text_field :actual %> <br/>

  <%= f.label :strength %>:
  <%= f.text_area :strength %> <br/>

  <%= f.label :weakness %>:
  <%= f.text_area :weakness %> <br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

outcomes/_outcome.html.erb

```
<%= outcomes.actual %>
<%= outcomes.strength %>
<%= outcomes.weakness %>
```

Can anyone help me by explaining why this error occurs and what i could do to make it work?

Comment: Which line of code are you getting the error on?

Comment: It might be that you need to pass your variables to your partial.

Comment: @Huy The error is on <%= outcomes.actual %> in the  outcomes/_outcome.html.erb file. Do you have a suggestion how i could pass the variables to the partial?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Huy I changed it to <%= @decision.outcomes.actual %> and i believe it worked but now i get the following error: undefined method `actual' for #<Outcome::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc6040723e0>

Comment: You have an active record association. Is `actual` an attribute of an Outcome object? If so, you can't call it on the association, you have to call it on the object itself. i.e. `@decision.outcomes.first.actual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to pass your variables as arguments to your partial. When you try to call `outcomes.actual`, it doesn't know what `outcomes` is. You either need to pass it as a local variable:

`<%= render "outcomes/outcome", locals: {outcomes: @decision.outcomes} %>`

or simply get it from your `@decision` instance variable:

**outcomes/_outcome.html.erb**

`<%= @decision.outcomes.actual %>`.